# Airflow Trigger Rule to run task only if parent task is in success/failed state

Tags: airflow

I want to run airflow task only if parent task state is `success`/`failed` and not in `upstream_failed` state.

None of trigger rules mentioned in [trigger_rule.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/utils/trigger_rule.py) is solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, custom trigger rules are not a thing in Airflow. The only way I can think of implementing this is using BranchPythonOperator.

The branch operator can check the state of the parent task as success or failure depending on which the downstream tasks can execute

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger_rule="ALL_DONE". it will execute your task even parent fail or succeed.